# Doubt about what my textbook claims about Taylor's formula?

Tags: taylor-expansion

My textbook is claiming this:

> Being, for Lagrange's remainder, $$f(x)-P_{n-1}(x) = \frac {f^{(n)}(\xi)( x-x_0 )^{n}}{n!}$$ you have, for some $\xi$ in $[x_0, x]$, that $$\frac{f(x)-P_{n}(x)}{(x-x_0)^n} = \frac {f^{(n)}(\xi) - f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}$$

Why is that true?

Comment: As a hint, can you fill in the blank: $P_n(x) = P_{n-1}(x) +$ ______?

Comment: @littleO: sure, easy task: $\frac{f^{n}(x_0)(x-x_0)^n}{n!}$

Comment: Cool, so that leads to the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $P_n(x) = P_{n-1}(x) + \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x - x_0)^n$, or equivalently
$$
P_{n-1}(x) = P_n(x) - \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x - x_0)^n.
$$
Now plug this equation for $P_{n-1}(x)$ into the equation
$$
f(x) - P_{n-1}(x) = \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)(x - x_0)^n}{n!}
$$
and you obtain
$$
\frac{f(x) - P_n(x)}{(x - x_0)^n} = \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi) - f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}.
$$

Comment: Really helpful, what I missed was $
P_{n-1}(x) = P_n(x) - \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x - x_0)^n.
$

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The actual definition is $$R_n:=\int_{x_0}^{x}f^{(n+1)}(t)\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}dt$$

If you try to solve that integral, you get that $$R_n=f^{(n+1)}(x_0)~\frac{(x-x_0)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+R_{n+1}$$

To get an estimate of $R_n$, you can use the mean value theorem (remember, $f\in C^{\infty}$)

[This is the paper where the estimate was published (not the first to publish it)](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/abramowitz_and_stegun.pdf)

Comment: You mean this was not known before 1964?

Comment: No, it was known before, I think it was first published by Lagrange in "Theorie des fonctions analytiques"

Comment: I had already done that, but to me it's still unclear...

Comment: What's not clear?